# ReactJS - State variables acting strangely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've started using React recently and have run into a problem seemingly related to state variables.

```
    bSort(){

        this.setState(
            state => {
                console.log("PRE BSORT STATE", state)
                let current_members = [...state.members];
                console.log("members pre BSORT", current_members);
                const updated_states = bubbleSort([...current_members]);
                return {states: updated_states, animate : true};
            },
            () => this.animate()
          );
    }
```

Here, I'm trying to update my state using information returned from the function bubbleSort. The issue is that the result of bubbleSort is strange:
I'm expecting an array of arrays, where each individual array represents a snapshot of the list as the sort progresses. Ideally, I would use each of these snapshots as a frame for my animation, but in reality the returned array is composed of multiple copies of the final result of the sort. This is odd, specially since I explicitly try to save the original and middle steps as the sort progresses. Please see the bubbleSort() code at the bottom.

I know there is a lot of text here but I would much appreciate help understanding what is happening, I am at a loss. Thank you!

EDIT:

I am adding the code for bubbleSort() so as to provide more information.

```
export default function bubbleSort(list){
    let members = [...list];
    let frames= [];
    //the original order of the members should be the first frame in the list
    frames.push(members);

    let early_exit = false;
    let wall = members.length;

    while(!early_exit){

        console.log("FRAMES WITHIN BSORT", frames);

        let last_change_index = null;
        for(var i = 0; i < wall; i++){
            if(members[i+1] != null){

                console.log("COMPARING", members[i].props.style.height, "AND", members[i+1].props.style.height);

                //Here we color red the two elements that will be compared
                var new_1 = React.cloneElement(
                    members[i],
                    {
                        style : {backgroundColor : "red", height : members[i].props.style.height}
                    }
                );
                var new_2 = React.cloneElement(
                    members[i+1],
                    {
                        style : {backgroundColor : "red", height : members[i+1].props.style.height}
                    }
                );
                members[i] = new_1;
                members[i+1] = new_2;

                //and add this new comparison state to the list of frames
                frames.push(members);

                //now we decide if we need to swap the elements
                if(members[i].props.style.height > members[i+1].props.style.height){

                    console.log("SWAPPING", i, i+1);
                    //If should swap, the two elements are colored yellow and shifted on the x axis
                    let new_1_yellow = React.cloneElement(
                        new_1,
                        {
                            animate : {x : 3},
                            style : {backgroundColor : "yellow", height : new_1.props.style.height}
                        }
                    );
                    let new_2_yellow = React.cloneElement(
                        new_2,
                        {
                            animate : {x : -3},
                            style : {backgroundColor : "yellow", height : new_2.props.style.height}
                        }
                    );

                    members[i+1] = new_1_yellow;
                    members[i] = new_2_yellow;

                    last_change_index = i;

                    frames.push(members);

                    //We change the yellow swapped members back to blue
                    let new_1_blue = React.cloneElement(
                        new_1_yellow,
                        {
                            animate : {x : 0},
                            style : {backgroundColor : "blue", height : new_1_yellow.props.style.height}
                        }
                    );

                    let new_2_blue = React.cloneElement(
                        new_2_yellow,
                        {
                            animate : {x : 0},
                            style : {backgroundColor : "blue", height : new_2_yellow.props.style.height}
                        }
                    );

                    members[i+1] = new_1_blue;
                    members[i] = new_2_blue;

                    //and add this return to blue state to the list
                    frames.push(members);

                }
                else{
                //Here we re-color blue the two elements that were compared
                    let new_1_blue = React.cloneElement(
                        new_1,
                        {
                            style : {backgroundColor : "blue", height : new_1.props.style.height}
                        }
                    );
                    let new_2_blue = React.cloneElement(
                        new_2,
                        {
                            style : {backgroundColor : "blue", height : new_2.props.style.height}
                        }
                    );
                    members[i] = new_1_blue;
                    members[i+1] = new_2_blue;

                    //and add this return to blue state to the list
                    frames.push(members);
                }
            }
        }
        if(last_change_index == null){
            early_exit = true;
        }
        wall = last_change_index;
    }
    return frames;
}
```

Comment: first you dont need to return an object with key **state** and there may be used decompose operator ***...*** . Your code: ```return {states : states, animate : true};``` with decomposition operator ```return {...states, animate : true};```. But nevertheless it doesnt answer your problem in 1st case. It's just improving

Comment: one more advice do not override an predifined variable ```let states = bubbleSort(members);``` because since the object creates links, they maybe misused in unclear may. Better define new clearly-named var ```let updatedStates = bubbleSort(members);``` and then put it back to ```return {...updatedStates, animate : true};```

Comment: if your bubbleSort returns an array, than better solution would be ```setState( state => {const sortedMembers = bubbleSort(state.members); return {members: sortedMembers, animate : true};``` or simplify your code ```setState(state => ({members: bubbleSort(state.members), animate: true}))```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have increased the clarity of variable names. My purpose for bubbleSort is to return an array, but this is an array of arrays, where each of the individual arrays is a snapshot of the list's current state as the sort progresses. I have updated my post with my bubbleSort implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's working like you expect, but the console is inspecting the value after it changes.

If `bubbleSort()` mutates your data in place, rather then returning a new pristine copy with your edits made, then your console is just holding onto an object reference, and then showing it's current values when you inspect it.

This is one of the reasons, and there are many other reasons, that you want to treat state immutably. Never change objects in state. Always provide new objects in state.

I bet this will fix your problem:

```
bubbleSort([...members]);
```

But you should probably implement bubble sort to return a new array or object, rather than modify an existing one.

Without the source of `bubbleSort` I can't say for sure this is right. But I've seen this behaviour before and this was the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have updated my post. Adding the [...members] syntax to the function call does fix the issue of the
```
console.log("PRE BSORT STATE", state)
```
printout. It now accurately reflects initial values - the larger issue remains that bubbleSort() is not returning results as intended. I've updated my initial post to reflect this. In short, I'm expecting it to return an array of arrays, where each array represents the current state of the list as the sort progresses. In execution, the function returns an array filled with multiple copies of the final result.

Comment: I have also removed example two since, after testing with the [...x] syntax, I have found you are correct about the console logs inspecting the values after they change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I don't fully understand the issue, but it sounds like you want one function to finish what it's supposed to do before the next function is fired.

```
  async bSort() {
    await this.setState(
      state => {
        console.log("PRE BSORT STATE", state);
        let members = state.members;
        let states = bubbleSort(members);
        return { states: states, animate: true };
      },
      () => this.animate()
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am currently getting errors from trying your solution. I installed "@babel/runtime" and "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" to get past the first few errors, but now I am getting "this.setStateAsync is not a function". Are there other dependencies I need before using setStateAsync? I have also updated the original post with more information.

Comment: @andresB try setState

Comment: When using setState, Visual Studio Code underlines the "await" word. Hovering over "await" shows the message:
"await has no effect on this type of expression".
The end result is the same - the array returned by bubbleSort contains nothing but copies of the list after it has been sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue had nothing to do with React State management, the entirety of the problem was due to how I handled arrays within my bubbleSort function. I needed to use the spread operator so that subsequent array operations would not affect the original array. Thanks for all the info provided!